# What sort of noise is this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, games

I'm a game developer not a graphic artist, so I'm not very good at any of this stuff, anyway, in my most recent project I have created a custom shader using a "glint" texture for some of the UI:

[image: glint]

At the moment it works fine, however, the texture I used has faded (circular) edges, and therefore you get patches where no glistening is present, and it's overall a bit inconsistent:

[image: faded edges]

Now this texture seems quite complicated, I believe it is meant to be some kind of "froth" or "foam" texture but I don't need it that complicated really. So my question is what kind of steps could I take and what kind of effects could generate this sort of effect in something like photoshop?

Comment: Hi. I wouldn't describe this as noise.  That's a very different thing.  I'd describe it possibly as a cloud or plasma effect, possibly a marble effect, sometimes called turbulence. Depends on the software you are using though.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop: `Filter > Render > Clouds`, or `Filter > Render > Difference Clouds`.

Holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key when selecting one of the filters increases the contrast of the filter.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I change the scale of said rendered clouds? Edit: right now they dont look like the froth because the clouds are huge.

Comment: That's a pretty basic operation - `Edit > Transform > Scale` You may benefit from some tutorials covering basic things.

Comment: I know how to do basic things, but this isn't quite my field. I mostly use photoshop for art, thanks anyways though

Comment: I didn't do it until now, but transform > scale just scales the image, that isn't what I mean, I know how to do that. I'm talking about how to scale the generated clouds, just like how you scale noise to make it more/less detailed.